# what is the difference between collection and array in php (propel)?

Tags: php, arrays, orm, propel, propel2

**Collections And On-Demand Hydration** 
The advantage of using *a collection instead of an array* is that Propel can hydrate model objects on demand. Using this feature, you'll never fall short of memory when retrieving a large number of results. Available through the setFormatter() method of Model Queries, on-demand hydration is very easy to trigger:

```
<?php
 $authors = AuthorQuery::create()
   ->limit(50000)
   ->setFormatter(ModelCriteria::FORMAT_ON_DEMAND)
   ->find();

foreach ($authors as $author) {
  echo $author->getFirstName();
}
```

1) **What is the meaning of "Hydration" here?** 
2) **what is the difference between collection and array?**

Source : [Propel @1.6](http://propelorm.org/Propel/documentation/03-basic-crud.html#collections-and-on-demand-hydration)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**1.Hidration**

A means to improve performance by "filling" your Class/Object with the row data just when you need it.

Instead of doing `"SELECT * FROM SomeTable"` from a very large table, Propel will initially fire off `"SELECT ID FROM SomeTable"`, then inside the loop, then do `"SELECT [COLUMS] FROM SomeTable WHERE ID=[CurrentID]"`, hence "On Demand"

**2. Collection vs Array**
Array is just the normal array, whereas a PropelCollection is an Object of Objects, which has a lot of stuff available such as:

- Paging results
- Checking for odd or even, `->isOdd()`, etc.
- Checking the number of items in it `$object->count()`
- Format converting `->toYAML()`, `->toCSV()`, `->toXML()`

Each item in the collection is a PropelObject, so you can still fetch data with `->getColumn()` inside your loop. [Documentation](http://propelorm.org/Propel/reference/model-criteria.html#collections-pager-and-formatters)